# How to make a executable from a NodeJS+Express app?

Tags: node.js, exe, nssm

I have a NodeJS + Express app which I'm using as a Print Server.

I should create an executable from this web application.

So far, I added [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) and [node-mac](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-mac) to make my app run as a service or daemon.

Now what I need is, creating Windows Executable or DMG so my users can execute and start to use my app.

There are some projects like [nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe) (No support for Exe files) and [EncloseJS](https://github.com/igorklopov/enclose) but I couldn't generate a working EXE file.

What should I use for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide [Standalone Express API Binaries with pkg](http://thecodebarbarian.com/standalone-express-apis-binaries-with-pkg.html) explains how to make standalone express executables.